# How can I programmatically create a backup of my iOS Calendar and of the Reminders in iOS?

Tags: ios, backup, icalendar, reminders

In the Mac Calendar app, I can save a backup archive with all calendar entries and all reminders. The backups file has the extension .icbu.

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to create this file programmatically on iOS?
2. How can I programmatically restore such a backup?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently according to the available [API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) there is no way, there are many other identical questions unanswered.

If the data format is not important you may (very brutal solution but i can't come up with anything better) retrieve all the items and create a file in .ics format that as far as i now is also exported and is known and easier to eventually parse. But my information is not updated so you may want to investigate more.

A little more here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4241341